# Prevent spam from a random email

Tags: email

Over the past week, I have been getting 50+ emails a day from a random email. These emails have a virus attached to them, so to prevent any damage, I manage them on my iPad. It has recently gotten much worse, and I want to have a way to filter these emails directly to trash. The problem is, the sender is different every time. It has a different username, title, content, subject, and domain each time. Is there a way to block them completely? I am using Gmail.

P.S: The emails also come from .com, .ca, .edu, among many other extensions.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to answer your question, because you didn't provide what email provider you are using.

Let's assume you manage your own email server, in order to prevent this, you'll need to install some virus and spam software to do the filtering for you. Most mail servers usually have a way to implement spam filtering and virus checking.

Check out:

- [Spam Assassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/)
- [Clam AV](http://www.clamav.net/)

These two are the most common spam and anti-virus software people use, that operate their own mail server.